# Java: display text in TrayIcon?

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program that will display the current weather in the Windows system tray. I have it nearly completed and the weather appears in the tooltip and I have a generic icon in the tray.

What I'm looking to now do is to have the temperature in the tray instead of a generic icon. Is it possible to display text in the tray?

Ultimately I would like to have 2 tray icons - one with the temperature in Fahrenheit and the one with the other in Celsius as I'm trying to learn them both. Is it possible to have two TrayIcons at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, yes you can have more than one TrayIcon per application, so long as the SystemTray is supported. Just add as many as you want. Each can have a different image and a different popup menu. Although putting a different menu on each trayicon would probably be quite confusing to the user!

Secondly, a TrayIcon can only be represented by an Image with a tooltip text. However you can always generate that image on the fly (including drawing text on the image), or update it, and then cause the TrayIcon to refresh the image by calling `<trayicon>.setImage()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In regards to multiple TrayIcons, is there any reason that I cannot add the same PopupMenu? I get the error "the PopupMenu is already set for another TrayIcon" when I try to. I understand what it is saying but must I really recreate the menu a second time for a second TrayIcon?

Comment: I imagine for the same reason you cannot add any component to more than one container at a time - each component needs to know its parent for various reasons, and the whole system is set up so that each component can have only one parent. :( Sorry!